# Display a label depending on a date in swift

Tags: string, swift, nsdate

Lets say i want to display a string depending on which date it is. 
For example if it is 2016-12-24 i want the string "Merry Christmas" to be displayed or if it is 2017-01-01 i want the text "Happy New Year".

This is what i got so far but i don't know how to add a string to it and hook it up to a label.

```
    let now = NSDate()
print(now)
now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

// March 10, 1876 was 3,938,698,800 seconds before the third millennium (January 1, 2001 midnight UTC)
let firstLandPhoneCallDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -3_938_698_800.0)

// April 3, 1973 was 875,646,000 seconds before the third millennium
let firstCellPhoneCallDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: -875_646_000.0)

// January 9, 2007, 18:00 UTC was 190,058,400 seconds after the third millennium
let iPhoneAnnouncementDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 190_058_400.0)

// January 27, 2010, 18:00 UTC was 286,308,000 seconds after the third millennium
let iPadAnnouncementDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 286_308_000.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you have a dictionary or database with dates and event names. In this example I will use simple dict like:

```
let eventsCalendar: Dictionary<String, String> = [
"0101": "Happpy New Year!",
//... other dates and events
]
```

In this example I use strings, but date can be NSDate.
Then turn today's NSDate into string, like:

```
func todaysDateAsString() -> String {

    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMdd"
    let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return str
}
```

And lastly, assign relevant content from dictionary to your label Outlet (you ctrl-drag a label onto ViewController code window and create an outlet name (not action, but outlet). Call it whatever, a label and then use method for that label - label.text

```
func todaysEventString(dateString: String) -> String {
    return eventsCalendar[dateString]!
}

label.text = todaysEventString(todaysDateAsString())
```

This was for today using just month and date. If you have events for many different years, you include a year in your database and use year in dateformatter.dateFormat.
In your case:

```
func DateAsString() -> String {

    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return str
}
```

And database holds keys in yyyy-MM-dd format:

```
 "1992-01-22": "Somebody's Birthday",
```

Comment: When I do it I get an error saying "Expected declaration"

Comment: 1) You should add an event for today, othervise it will crash as dictitem is unwrapped forcibly  "!" mark here: return eventsCalendar[dateString]! so it says there's always a value in dict. Use if let ... optional unwrapping.
2) You need to create a label in storyboard, ctrl-drag it to code create IBOutlet. Give a name for that name for label, for example, if you call an outlet "eventLabel", you change this string eventLabel.text = todaysEventString(todaysDateAsString()) using eventLabel name.

Glad, my code did help, please don't forget to checkmark great answers! Welcome to Stack community!

Answer (score 1):

Here, this works perfectly:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  temp
//
//  Created by thinkswift on 12.01.16.
//  Copyright © 2016. thinkswift. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    let eventsCalendar: Dictionary<String, String> = [
        "1992-01-22": "Somebody's Birthday",
        "2016-01-12": "Johns Birthday"
        //... other dates and events
    ]

    func DateAsString() -> String {

        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        return str
    }

    func todaysEventString(dateString: String) -> String {
        return eventsCalendar[dateString]!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        myLabel.text = todaysEventString(DateAsString())
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Helped me out a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let eventsCalendar: Dictionary<String, String> = [
    "1992-01-22": "Somebody's Birthday",
    //... other dates and events
]

func DateAsString() -> String {

    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return str
}

func todaysEventString(dateString: String) -> String {
    return eventsCalendar[dateString]!
}

label.text = todaysEventString(todaysDateAsString())
```

}

Comment: This label.text = todaysEventString(todaysDateAsString()) must be within 
viewDidLoad() {

}

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 update - works for me in Xcode 8.02

```
 let date = NSDate()
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy" // Set the way the date should be displayed
 dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: date as Date)
```